# Accessing dictionary inside Django template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am customizing my item query result and marking these items as added in the cart based on *DB* values, i have succeeded in making this dictionary but the issue is how to access its values now inside the *template*

**my view**

```
menu_items =[]
            menus = MenuItem.objects.all().order_by('-date_added')
            for item in menus:
                print(item.id)
                menus_added['item']=item
                if item.id in cartitem:
                    menus_added['is_added']=True
                else:
                    menus_added['is_added']=False
                menu_items.append(menus_added)
                menus_added = {}
        print(menu_items)
        restaurants = Restaurants.objects.all()
        categories= Category.objects.all()
        return render(request,'store/store.html',context={
        'product':menu_items,    <-- i want access this dictionary
        'restaurants':restaurants,
        'categories':categories
    })
```

this approach is not working

**template**

```
{% for item in product.item %}
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <figure class="card card-product-grid">
            <div class="img-wrap"> 
                
                <img src="{{item.image_url}}">
                
            </div> <!-- img-wrap.// -->
            <figcaption class="info-wrap">
                <div class="fix-height">
                    <a href="{% url 'menus:item' item.id %}" class="title">{{item.item_name}}</a>
                    <div class="price-wrap mt-2">
                        <span class="price">{{item.price}}</span>
                        <del class="price-old">${{item.price}}</del>
                    </div> <!-- price-wrap.// -->
                </div>
                {% if is_added %}
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-success">Added ! </a>
                {% else %}
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Add to cart </a>
                {% endif %}
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div> <!-- col.// -->
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need for loop here({% for item in product.item %}), just try `{{product.image_url}}`, not `{{item.image_url}}`
or `{{ product.price }}`, not `{{item.price}}`

Comment: it's not working , i need  to iterate over item list